# Does having mucinious carcinoma in one tissue influence the risk of getting a mucinious carcinoma in an other tissue?

Tags: cancer

I just read the [Cleveland Clinic's article](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/22975-mucinous-carcinoma) about Mucinous carcinoma:

> Mucinous carcinoma is a rare type of cancer. It starts in the main cells of mucus, called mucin. Although this type of cancer can develop anywhere, it’s most common in your breast.

The article also says:

> Mucinous carcinoma is rare. It’s most common in breast cancer, accounting for about 7% of cases. It also accounts for:
> About 3% of ovarian cancer.
> Less than 5% of lung cancer.
> About 9% of rectal cancer.
> Less than 10% of endometrial (uterine) cancer.
> About 15% of colon cancer.

Now I am curious: is being diagnosed with *e.g.* mucinous breast cancer a risk factor for developing *e.g.* mucinous lung cancer? Is the risk decreased due to system-wide treatment, like chemotherapy?

(In case that question is too specific: I'd also accept answers that show whether or not research regarding the risk assessment for different mucinous carcinomes is done at all.)

Comment: Well, like many cancers it can metastasize so it can go pretty much anywhere there are mucin cells.

Comment: @CareyGregory Would mucinous breast cancer metastases in the the lung  look different from de novo mucinous lung cancer? Or are they not distinguishable?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but images of the tumor in google all look about the same. They may differ in other ways that can't be seen.